# opensuse 13.2 installation

Tags: linux, opensuse

I have 1 tb hard disk in that I have installed windows 8.1 which occupies 2 partition windows/system reserved then I have 1 NTFS partition for my data and 1 extended partition in which I have installed elementary os ,now I want to install opens use 13.2 by replacing elementary os without affecting windows and other NTFS partitions , please help

Answer (score 0):

I booted the installation media optional to uefi  and I was able to install opens use easily :-)